# Set Azure FileShare Size - ARM Template

Tags: azure, file-sharing, quota, azure-storage, azure-arm-template

I'm looking for a way to set the **quota size** (ex, 100gb) for the file share I am deploying using Azure ARM Templates. As of now when I deploy it defaults to 5TB which is not ideal. Ideally I would just add a setting to my **template.json or parameter.json files** that would adjust this setting but I haven't come across anything yet. I'd appreciate any help/guidance on this.

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "storageAccountName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "fileShareName": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 3,
            "maxLength": 63
        },
        "fileShareName1": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 3,
            "maxLength": 63
        },
        "fileShareName2": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 3,
            "maxLength": 63
        },
        "accountType": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "kind": {
            "type": "string"
        },        
        "accessTier": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": {
            "type": "bool"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "accessTier": "[parameters('accessTier')]",
                "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": "[parameters('supportsHttpsTrafficOnly')]"
            },
            "dependsOn": [],
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('accountType')]"
            },
            "kind": "[parameters('kind')]",
        "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares",
            "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
            "properties": {
                "shareQuota": "100"
            },
            "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccountName'), '/default/', parameters('fileShareName'))]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
            ]
        },

        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares",
            "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
            "properties": {
                "shareQuota": "100"
            },
            "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccountName'), '/default/', parameters('fileShareName1'))]",
            "shareQuota": "100",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
            ]
        },

        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares",
            "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
            "properties": {
                "shareQuota": "100"
            },
            "name": "[concat(parameters('storageAccountName'), '/default/', parameters('fileShareName2'))]",
            "shareQuota": "100",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
            ]
        }

    ]
}
    ],
    "outputs": {}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ARM resource for creating file shares supports providing a quota size using the shareQuota property, this value is in GB.

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares",
  "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
  "properties": {
    "shareQuota": "100"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried adding the "shareQuota" property to my template.json file and I get the following error - "The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'shareQuota' on object of type 'TemplateResource'. Path 'properties.template.resources[0].resources[0].shareQuota'

Comment: Can you show the whole template?

Comment: added it above to the initial question

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to remove some previous settings from my code above when I posted it. I was able to get it working by adding the setting you mentioned. I have the following for each share:                                                                                       {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares",
            "apiVersion": "2019-04-01",
            "properties": {
                "shareQuota": "100"
            },